# C# - about Windows.Forms Timer and SMTPClient.SendAsync

Tags: c#, events, timer, smtpclient, sendasync

I have a `Windows.Form Timer` that triggers an event every x minutes(5 minutes for example). Basically when that event is triggered, it sends an email out. I used the `SMTPClient.SendAsync();` but it does not send the email out successfully. I tried debugging it but there are no errors whatsoever. The code executes fine when I step over that specific line during debug mode.

The `SMTPClient.Send(mail);` is working however. But I don't want that for my program since it stops the thread until it's finished executing.

This did not happen when I was using System.Timers.Timer. The `SendAsync` function was working fine before I switched to the `Windows.Form Timer`. I was able to receive the emails so it can't be the mail settings such as the port,server,credentials, etc.

Is `SendAsync` not compatible with an event that is triggered by a `Windows.Form Timer`? Because it was working when I used `System.Timers.Timer`

Comment: Why you can't still use System.Timers.Timer?

Comment: I switch to Windows.Form Timer so that I have control on the UI(such as clearing a textbox from the event). I can't do that when using System.Timers.Timer. The email that I'm sending contains whatever is in the textbox. After the email is sent, I'll clear the textbox for new logs. Rinse and repeat

Comment: Add some code, maybe you're doing something wrong.

Comment: I've found this on MSDN: "The Windows Forms Timer component is single-threaded, and is limited to an accuracy of 55 milliseconds. If you require a multithreaded timer with greater accuracy, use the Timer class in the System.Timers namespace." Could be this that doesn't allow you to use SendAsync?